# Me sale este Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`laboratoriosql`.`articuloxpedido`, CONSTRAINT `

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

> Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`laboratoriosql`.`articuloxpedido`, CONSTRAINT `articuloxpedido_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_ped_artped`) REFERENCES `pedido` (`id_ped`))

```
create table articulo
(
id_art int auto_increment not null,
tit_art varchar (100) not null,
aut_art varchar (100) not null,
edi_art varchar (300) not null,
prec_art decimal not null,
primary key (id_art)
)auto_increment = 1;
create table pedido
(
id_ped int primary key auto_increment not null,
id_cli_ped varchar (11) not null,
fec_ped date not null,
val_ped decimal not null,
foreign key (id_cli_ped) references cliente (id_cli)
) auto_increment=1;

create table articuloxpedido
(
id_ped_artped int not null,
id_art_artped int not null,
can_art_artped int not null,
val_ven_art_artped decimal not null,
foreign key (id_ped_artped) references pedido (id_ped),
foreign key (id_art_artped) references articulo (id_art)
);

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

insert into articulo
values
(1,'Redes cisco','Ernesto Arigasello','Alfaomega-Rama','60000'),
(null,'Facebook y Twitter para adultos','Veloso Claudio','Alfaomega','52000'),
(null,'Creacion de un portal con php y mysql','Jacob Pavón Puertas','Alfaomega-Rama','40000'),
(null,'Administración de sistemas operativos','Julio Gomez López','Alfaomega-Rama','55000');

insert into pedido
values
(1,'63502718','2012-02-25','120000'),
(null,'77191956','2012-04-30','55000'),
(null,'63502718','2011-12-10','260000'),
(null,'1098765789','2012-02-25','1800000');

insert into articuloxpedido
values
('1','3','5','40000'),
('1','4','12','55000'),
('2','1','5','65000'),
('3','2','10','55000'),
('3','3','12','45000'),
('4','1','20','65000');
```

Esta ultima son los valores a ingresa

Comment: Me sale ese error cuando intento ingresar los datos de la tercera tabla, no es si es porque esta no tiene PK o si debo definir esas llaves foranes como PK, he visto que las tablas donde solo hay llaves foráneas las ponen como pk, será por eso el error.?

Comment: El código debe ir como texto, no como imagen, pulsa en [edit] para cambiarlo.

Comment: Falta la tabla cliente. Eliminé la fk hacia el cliente que está en pedido `foreign key (id_cli_ped) references cliente (id_cli)`, y se ejecutó todo correctamente.